# Error when trying to open a new chat in Whatsapp without reloading the page

Tags: electron, whatsapp

I'm using Electron to create a script that open in whatsapp, the number received to chat.

Actually I access the URL http://127.0.0.1:3400/whatsapp/554195561535/hi and in Electron, the backend should open the new number in whatsapp app.

Inside the function `createWindow()`, I have this function:

```
function enviar(numero, mensagem){
    win.webContents.executeJavaScript(`
      let link = document.createElement("a");
      link.setAttribute("href", 'whatsapp://send?phone=${numero}');
      document.body.append(link);
      link.click();
      document.body.removeChild(link);
      console.log("phone: "+phone);
    `,true).then(console.log('JavaScript Executed Successfully'));
}
```

But the code are opening the right phone in whatsapp to chat, BUT AFTER THAT, some errors appear:

[IMAGE EXAMPLE OF ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07k3X.png)

Comment: is there any creation of a new window in your code from the renderer side. In another word, creating a window from javascript dom!?

Answer (score 0):

Did reloading the page work?

If it did then you should add an error text: 'Please Reload' or something like that. If it didn't then You should try to make sure that you can't find a bug in the code.